# Java.net server example doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new to java.net and trying to make a simple client-server app. here is the server code:

```
public class Consumer extends Thread{

    public Socket s;
    int num;

    public Consumer(int num, Socket s){
        this.num = num;
        this.s = s;

        setDaemon(true);
        setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            int i = 0;

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3128, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));

            System.out.println("server started");
            while (true){
                new Consumer(i, server.accept());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();

            byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
            int r = is.read(buf);

            String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

            data = "" +num+": " +"\n" + data;

            os.write(data.getBytes());

            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("init error: " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

When I start it - nothing bad happens but when I send smth from some client I get the following:

```
init error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What does e.printStackTrace() give you?

Comment: I dont know the case with you.but when i run your code, My program hangs at this line : new Consumer(i, server.accept()); May be your Producer class is not producing some data.i suggest run ur producer class before this consumer one if the Producer class exists.

Comment: Can u give the link from where u got the above code?

Comment: @rahulserver it's russian, but here you are: http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/article02.html

Comment: I ran the code as in my answer below and it works. R u able to pass cmd line args?

Comment: @EJP it is not the same. there I asked why my producer app doesn't work and here I ask why my server code doesn't work. As for me they are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read data from an input stream, you know you've reached the end of the stream when `read` returns -1. It looks like that's what happens here: r comes out as -1 because there's no data to be read, and then the program goes on to try to create a string with a *negative* number of characters.

You should always check the return values of functions for error conditions:

```
        int r = is.read(buf);

        if (r < 0) return; /* end of stream was reached */
```

Also, when handling exceptions you should print the stack trace. The stack trace tells you on which line of the program the exception happened. Without that information you have to start the debugging process by guessing.

```
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("init error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: your answer is the most useful

Answer (score 2):

Probably your

```
int r = is.read(buf);
```

is returning `-1` and hence this code fails :

```
String data = new String(buf, 0, r);
```

Check for the end of the stream :

```
int bytesRead;
while( (bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
 // then create a String from the byte[]
}
```

Look the documentation of [InputStream#read(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D))

> **Returns:**
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or **-1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.**

And the documentation of [String(byte[] bytes,int offset,int length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,int,int))

> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - If the offset and the length arguments index characters outside the bounds of the bytes array

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem.In the [link](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/article02.html) you have pasted , you need to run the program SampleClient with command line arguments test1,test2, abc,mno. Try running as mentioned in the link as:

```
java SampleClient test1
java SampleClient test2
...
java SampleClient testN
```

Actually your program is not running because it is not getting a data to read as it has no arguments so

```
int r = is.read(buf);
```

is returning -1 hence the exception.

Comment: when I run it in terminal it gives me the following: `a/dlp/main$ java Main.class test1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at `

Comment: `java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main.class. Program will exit.`

Comment: what is your class name? If it is SampleClient, firstly compile using javac SampleClient.java and then java SampleClient. Refer this link for further instructions:http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html also are u passing command line arguments to SampleClient like java SampleClient test1 ?

Comment: I did everything as described and have the same stacktrace

Comment: Using what command are u running your code?

Comment: java Main(I called it so) test1

Comment: lets cm 2 chat room if u want as i think this discussion is geting long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33491/discussion-between-nikitin-mikhail-and-rahulserver)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was that you have started your program without passing command-line arguments.

You should learn from your mistakes. In the future study the input and the output of your systems carefully.

Also, you should get more information from the exceptions, so stack trace is your friend.

Finally, an IDE would be helpful for you. For instance you could download NetBeans or Eclipse and they would significantly simplify your life as a developer.

Comment: you know, I've tryed to start it using IDE firstly but after a few boss shots I've decided to try it in the console. In the IDe I seen that sender sends message but receiver doesn't